# this.elem does not recognize inside the object constuctor

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I'm trying to create a simple constructor for `eventListeners mouseover/out`, but I ran into the one error - my object constructor `HoverIntent` does not want to recognize the `this.elem` value inside own method `this.over`?

P.S.
Forgive me for such insane indents in the code, they are placed by the internal editor at insertion.

```js
 function HoverIntent(elem) {

   this.elem = elem; // recognize normaly
   this.over = function() {
    var tooltip = document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.className = "tooltip";
    tooltip.innerHTML = "some-usefull-text";

     tooltip.style.left = this.elem.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px'; 
            // this.elem - getting an error
     tooltip.style.top = this.elem.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 5 + 'px'; 
            // this.elem - getting an error

     document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
   };
   this.out = function() {

    var current = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip')[0];
     document.body.removeChild(current);
   };
 };

  elem.addEventListener( 'mouseover', new HoverIntent(elem).over );
  elem.addEventListener( 'mouseout', new HoverIntent(elem).out );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
 
 .clock {
     border: 1px dashed yellow;
     padding: 5px;
     display: inline-block;
     background: red;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
 }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="elem" class="clock">
   <span class="hours">14</span> :
   <span class="minutes">45</span> :
   <span class="seconds">10</span>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this` is not the same inside the inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
this.over = function() {
```

with

```
this.over = () => {
```

This will cause the listener to be in the context of its constructor, and not the DOM element it was triggered on

Comment: This is a good ES6 solution. Maybe is it possible to make such trick by standard ES5 methods (maybe we need closers)? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @sviat just append `.bind(this)` to the regular function to get the same result

Comment: And a small side note: closures are related to scope and not to context...